# How to calculate average time Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

i'm trying to execute a query that would give me the average time of a Race knowing that my table is structured as follow

```
RunnerID,   State,   Timestamp_race
R1          start     2017-04-11 12:15:15.722415
R2          start     2017-04-11 13:15:15.722415
R1          finish    2017-04-11 15:15:15.722415
R1          finish    2017-04-11 17:15:15.722415
```

the runners starts at different times and end at different times the idea is to calculate the average time for the whole race

Comment: Please show us what you already tried, so we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like R1 finished twice and R2 never finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extract(epoch)` to get the seconds for each race and then take the average:

```
select avg(seconds) as avg_seconds
from (select runnerid, extract(epoch from max(Timestamp_race) - min(Timestamp_race)) as seconds
      from t
      group by runnerid
     ) r;
```

This assumes that the minimum time is the start and the maximum is the end.

EDIT:

If you want the average as an interval, you can do:

```
select avg(diff) as avg_diff
from (select runnerid, (max(Timestamp_race) - min(Timestamp_race)) as diff
      from t
      group by runnerid
     ) r;
```

Comment: There's no need to extract the epoch from the difference of the timestamps.  PostgreSQL naturally returns an interval data type when subtracting timestamps.  The default format is a bit verbose, but the `TO_CHAR` function with an appropriate mask e.g. `'DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'` will help with that.

Comment: @Sentinel . . . I think seconds are a nice format, but you have a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nicer format:

```
select to_char(avg(seconds),'DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') as avg_time
from (select runnerid, max(Timestamp_race) - min(Timestamp_race) as seconds
      from race t
      group by runnerid
     ) r;

|        avg_time |
|-----------------|
| 00 03:30:00.000 |
```